# Is it possible to change the birthday format in calender?

Tags: calendar

I’m showing the address book birthday’s in the calendar app but I hate that every thing I can see ist “xx. birthday of N…“ and not mor because the labels are to narrow. To see who’s birthday it is I need to click on the event.

[image: calendar]

Is it possible to an other fromat like `<name> (<xx>. Birthday)`

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can turn off the iCal birthday calendar and download [Dates 2 iCal 2](http://www.nhoj.co.uk/datestoical) which allows you to sync birthdays (and anniversaries) and customize the text to your preference.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work fine, but other ways are still welcome …